# How to get bar datas on Stock tickers using ib-insync?

Tags: algorithmic-trading, ib-insync

When I try to get Bar data of Stock tickers like("AMZN", "AAPL" etc.) not getting any output, but successfully able to retrieve data for Forex tickers like ("EURUSD", "AUDUSD" etc.). I looked for lots of sources to find a way, but couldn't come across any solution so far.

This is the code below

```
from ib_insync import *
util.startLoop()

ib = IB()
ib.connect('127.0.0.1', 7497, clientId=14)

contract = Stock('IBM', 'SMART', 'USD')
# contract = Forex("EURUSD")

bars = ib.reqHistoricalData(
        contract,
        endDateTime='',
        durationStr='1 D',
        barSizeSetting='1 min',
        whatToShow='MIDPOINT',
        useRTH=True,
        formatDate=1,
        keepUpToDate=True)

def onBarUpdate(bars, hasNewBar):
    print(bars[-1])


bars.updateEvent += onBarUpdate

ib.run()
```

if I change the contract with Forex then its giving the desired output.